# Adding user roles without access to permissions

Tags: 7, users

I want an administrator to add roles to a user without having access to admin/user/permissions where he can alter user permissions.
Currently, on the user permissions form there is only one checkbox that allowes neither one of them or both.
What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Role Delegation](http://drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module.